# how to edit values in a nested dictionary based on the key value and the nested value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm trying to create a function that will go through a nested dictionary and  add the value of a key to a nested value, and create a new nested key-value pair. So for instance this input:

```
current_dict = {1: {'int1': 11}, 2: {'int1': 12}, 3: {'int1': 13}, 4: {'int1': 14}, 
5: {'int1': 15}}
```

would look like this output:

```
new_dict = {1: {'int1': 11, 'int2': 12}, 2: {'int1': 12, 'int2', 14}, 
3: {'int1': 13, 'int2', 16}, 4: {'int1': 14, 'int2': 18}, 5: {'int1': 15, 'int2', 20}}
```

I was working with a non-nested dictionary with something similar to add key-value pairs to create a new value using this:

```
int_dict = {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15}
new_dict2 = {}

def func2(k, v):
    new_k = k + v
    return new_k

for k, v in integer_dictionary.items():
    new_dict2[k] = func2(k, v)
```

and returns this:

```
{1: 12, 2: 14, 3: 16, 4: 18, 5: 20}
```

Ideally I would like to build out this function to be able to handle nested dictionaries as described above, but I'm not sure how to handle iterating through the nested elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
current_dict = {1: {'int1': 11}, 2: {'int1': 12}, 3: {'int1': 13}, 4: {'int1': 14}, 5: {'int1': 15}}
new_dict = {a:{**b, 'int2':b['int1']+a} for a, b in current_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'int1': 11, 'int2': 12}, 2: {'int1': 12, 'int2': 14}, 3: {'int1': 13, 'int2': 16}, 4: {'int1': 14, 'int2': 18}, 5: {'int1': 15, 'int2': 20}}
```

Edit: without a comprehension:

```
def funct2(k, v):
     return {**v, 'int2':v['int1']+k} 

for a, b in current_dict.items():
   current_dict[a] = funct2(a, b)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'int1': 11, 'int2': 12}, 2: {'int1': 12, 'int2': 14}, 3: {'int1': 13, 'int2': 16}, 4: {'int1': 14, 'int2': 18}, 5: {'int1': 15, 'int2': 20}}
```

Comment: is there a way to get this to work without using a dict comprehension? so basically same structure but just by using a for loop?

Comment: thanks for putting this together. sorry for the additional questions, but how would this work with a function? I'm new to python so trying to figure out how I can pass two values (i.e. a key and a value) into a function and then use the for loop you put together to iterate through everything. I want to figure out how to keep it as close as possible to the script I used above:                           

def func2(k, v):
    new_k = k + v
    return new_k

for k, v in integer_dictionary.items():
    new_dict2[k] = func2(k, v)

Comment: @David glad to help! Please see my recent edit. I incorporated your original `funct2` function with the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A function that can do that could look like:

#### Code:

```
def add_new_value_from_key_value(a_dict, key_add_from, key_to_add):
    a_dict = a_dict.copy()
    for k, v in a_dict.items():
        v[key_to_add] = k + v[key_add_from]
    return a_dict
```

#### Test Code:

```
current_dict = {1: {'int1': 11}, 2: {'int1': 12}, 3: {'int1': 13},
                4: {'int1': 14}, 5: {'int1': 15}
                }

new_dict = {
    1: {'int1': 11, 'int2': 12},
    2: {'int1': 12, 'int2': 14},
    3: {'int1': 13, 'int2': 16},
    4: {'int1': 14, 'int2': 18},
    5: {'int1': 15, 'int2': 20}
}

print(add_new_value_from_key_value(current_dict, 'int1', 'int2'))
assert new_dict == add_new_value_from_key_value(current_dict, 'int1', 'int2')
```

#### Results:

```
{
    1: {'int1': 11, 'int2': 12}, 
    2: {'int1': 12, 'int2': 14}, 
    3: {'int1': 13, 'int2': 16}, 
    4: {'int1': 14, 'int2': 18}, 
    5: {'int1': 15, 'int2': 20}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this is very useful. Is there a way to do this without taking a dictionary as an input? I'm making some edits and I would like to write it so it just takes 2 integers as inputs (i.e. a key and a value).

Comment: Aren't you going to need a the dict to get the lookup values you need?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
current_dict = {1: {'int1': 11}, 2: {'int1': 12}, 3: {'int1': 13}, 4: {'int1': 14}, 5: {'int1': 15}}

new_dict = current_dict.copy()

for k, v in new_dict.iteritems():
    v['int2'] = v['int1'] + k
```